# SQL create table stored procedure not setting defaults properly

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a table with a stored procedure.  I scripted the table as a CREATE statement and copied the file contents into my procedure, which works great.  Except that when it sets defaults, it sets the first columns default as the whole second line.

Here's the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCreatetblLocation]
AS
EXEC 
('
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblLocation](
  [pkLocationID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [fldName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
  [fldPath] [nvarchar](1000) NOT NULL,
  [fkYearID] [int] NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_LocationID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
  (
   [pkLocationID] ASC
  )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
  ) ON [PRIMARY]

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblLocation] ADD  DEFAULT N'' FOR [fldName]

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblLocation] ADD  DEFAULT N'' FOR [fldPath]
 ')
```

After execution, column `[fldName]` has a default value of `FOR [fldName] ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblLocation] ADD  DEFAULT N'' FOR [fldPath]`

It makes sense that it's just not recognizing the second quotation mark in (N''), but why not?  And how do I fix it?

**UPDATE:**

I have learned that the proper way to create tables is through reading and executing sql script files.  This keeps data manipulation and database manipulation seperate, and easier to manage.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Lots of product specific SQL there...)

Comment: Looks like sql server

Comment: Why do you need to create a table in a stored procedure?

Comment: I would like my application to install itself into a clients sql server.  I will have them create the database, but I need a way to create the required tables. Is there a better way?

Comment: Why are you using `EXEC` to run your code, passing it in as a string? Why not just have the code itself in your procedure? There's nothing dynamic I can see, so that seems unnecessary?

Comment: For deployment and config you usually just run a deployment SQL script. There are many ways to automate it i.e. through `SQLCMD.EXE`

Comment: @beardedmogul You should have separate .sql scripts to create the required tables, not a stored procedure to do this deployment. It's bad practice and it's not what stored procedures are for.

Comment: @3N1GM4 It works :)

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu May I ask why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an apostrophe within a string in SQL, you need to escape it with an additional apostrophe. Try:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCreatetblLocation]
AS
EXEC 
('
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblLocation](
  [pkLocationID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [fldName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
  [fldPath] [nvarchar](1000) NOT NULL,
  [fkYearID] [int] NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_LocationID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
  (
   [pkLocationID] ASC
  )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
  ) ON [PRIMARY]

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblLocation] ADD  DEFAULT N'''' FOR [fldName]

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblLocation] ADD  DEFAULT N'''' FOR [fldPath]
 ')
```

It's not clear (to me at least) why you're doing it this way though, instead of just:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCreatetblLocation]
AS
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblLocation](
  [pkLocationID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [fldName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
  [fldPath] [nvarchar](1000) NOT NULL,
  [fkYearID] [int] NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_LocationID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
  (
   [pkLocationID] ASC
  )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
  ) ON [PRIMARY]

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblLocation] ADD  DEFAULT N'' FOR [fldName]

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblLocation] ADD  DEFAULT N'' FOR [fldPath]
```

Also not clear why you're creating a table within a procedure, especially without checking whether it already exists first - can you guarantee that this table won't already exist every time your procedure is run?

Comment: I check that in my code with another procedure, along with 4 other tables.

Comment: There's a lot about what you're asking and what it seems you're doing which doesn't look like very good practice. Even if you are checking for the table's existence somewhere else before calling this stored procedure, the fact that it is possible to call this sproc without first checking that the table doesn't already exist is not a good thing at all. If you're going to create a table and there's any chance at all it could already exist, you should do that check within the same scope, so that it's never possible to try and create the table when it already exists.

Comment: Fair enough.  I am curious though, why it is not good practice to create tables with stored procedures.

Comment: I only said it's not clear why you're creating a table within a stored procedure, not that doing so is necessarily bad practice (although it seems a bit strange to me - why do you need to frequently re-create this table and as such want it saved as a stored procedure?). Allowing a scenario where it's possible to call a stored procedure which attempts to create a table which may already exist is definitely not a good idea, unless this is some kind of low-impact non-production situation and you understand the risks.

Comment: I could of course be way off the mark though and this is something totally standard within certain industries, applications or realms of SQL Server usage which I'm not familiar with - I learned by trying things out and researching, rather than any kind of formal guidance, so my perception of what's "good practice" could definitely be skewed!

Comment: I get the risk of overwriting a table. I'll change that.  Mr. Radu Gheorghiu is adamant that this is not the correct way to create a table.  My question is, why?  From what I've read, to execute a .sql file, you have to read the contents anyway.  How is that different than simply putting the contents in a stored procedure?

Comment: @beardedmogul ["A stored procedure is nothing more than prepared SQL code that you save so you can reuse the code over and over again."](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/160/sql-server-stored-procedure-tutorial/). Now, because you're not intending to write and create this table over and over again, but only once, there is no point in putting it in a stored procedure, even if you do error handling. Your code & database objects repository would be cleaner. I'd prefer to keep my deployment scripts separate, my procedures separate etc. Just because you can, doesn't mean that you should

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu That's fair. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You have to double the quotation marks when inside a string:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCreatetblLocation]
AS
EXEC ('
   SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblLocation](
  [pkLocationID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [fldName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
  [fldPath] [nvarchar](1000) NOT NULL,
  [fkYearID] [int] NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_LocationID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
  (
   [pkLocationID] ASC
  )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
  ) ON [PRIMARY]

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblLocation] ADD  DEFAULT N'''' FOR [fldName]

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblLocation] ADD  DEFAULT N'''' FOR [fldPath]
 ')`
```

Answer (score 0):

Not saying it is the right thing to do to create a table via stored procedure but...you need to escape your quotes:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCreatetblLocation]
AS
EXEC 
('
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblLocation](
  [pkLocationID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [fldName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
  [fldPath] [nvarchar](1000) NOT NULL,
  [fkYearID] [int] NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_LocationID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
  (
   [pkLocationID] ASC
  )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
  ) ON [PRIMARY]

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblLocation] ADD  DEFAULT N'''' FOR [fldName]

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblLocation] ADD  DEFAULT N'''' FOR [fldPath]
 ')
```